# WPF TwoWay binding in multiple UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, inotifypropertychanged

I have multiple `UserControl` which contain a shared `ViewModel`.

[image: Overview here]

It's a `DataGrid` where the user click on a row to see the detail of the row (the actual structure is more complex).

The problem is when I handle the `SelectionChanged` in the grid, I update the shared `ViewModel` to update the ContactDetail but it doesn't update the value in the `TextBoxes` (the object is updated in ContactDetail but values are not displayed).

**ListContact.xaml.cs**

```
public void contactsTable_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    contacts.current_identity = //Get the associated `IdentityViewModel`
}
```

**ContactDetail.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ContactDetail : UserControl
{
    public ContactsViewModel contacts;
    public DetailContact(ContactsViewModel contacts)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.contacts = contacts;
        this.DataContext = contacts;
    }
}
```

**ContactDetail.xaml**

```
 <UserControl x:Class="ContactDetail">
   <TextBox Name='address' Text="{Binding Path=contacts.current_identity.address, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   <TextBox Name='phone' Text="{Binding Path=contacts.current_identity.phone, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   <TextBox Name='email' Text="{Binding Path=contacts.current_identity.email, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
 </UserControl>
```

**ContactsViewModel.cs** (IdentityViewModel uses the same structure)

```
public class ContactsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Contact> _contacts;
    public List<Contact> contacts;
    {
        get { return _contacts; }
        set { _contacts = value; OnPropertyChanged("contacts"); }
    }

    private IdentityViewModel _current_identity;
    public IdentityViewModel current_identity
    {
        get { return _current_identity; }
        set { _current_identity = value; OnPropertyChanged("current_identity"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The question is, why doesn't this work and how to notify `ContactDetail` so that it displays the new value ?

Comment: You don't need to pass an instance of a reference type by `ref` as long as you don't change the reference ("pointer") itself. A `class` instance will always be passed by reference, a `struct` will be copied.

Comment: Are you sure your view-models raise the `PropertyChanged` event when needed? Please post your view-models.

Comment: @dymanoid Edited, and yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

Your data for contacts changes but the original reference location `Binding Path=contacts.current_identity.address` is still being referred to in the binding. I.E. `address` is still valid and has not changed. What changed was `contacts.current` but you are not binding to that.

Remember that binding is simply reflection to a *location reference*. If the original `address` changes you would see a change because that is what is being looked for to have a change. But instead the parent instance is what changed.

You need to refactor your bindings to allow for proper update when the `current_identity` changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
What you mean in "You need to refactor your bindings to allow for proper update when the current_identity changes." is that I need to update the `DataContext` each time I change the `current_identity` ?

Comment: I do that actually, catching the `OnPropertyChanged` event and then rebinding my data in each `UserControl`. Somehow, it works with `DataGrid` with redefining the `ItemsSource` but not with the `TextBox` when redefining `DataContext`